# Web app failed to start, cased by org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup, root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, tomcat

I've been on this issue for days now. I run my web app with Tomcat using Intellij IDE. I could not find why there is "IllegalArgumentException" or what arguments caused the issue. I tried to update the libraries, Tomcat (8, 9, 10), even the IDE itself. I could not find anything useful on the web.

I appreciate if you can shed light on the cause, and if possible how to track the root cause in such cases.

Below is the stack trace from Tomcat logs and pom.xml and web.xml.

Thank you

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>webAPI</groupId>
    <artifactId>webAPI</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>webAPI</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>resources</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.10</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>CRM-DB2 API</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WEBAPI</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WEBAPI</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

```
05-Oct-2022 09:12:10.434 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Servlet.init() for servlet [WEBAPI] threw exception
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$2.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:104)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:102)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4958)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
05-Oct-2022 09:12:10.434 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [WEBAPI] in web application [/crmDb2API-1.0] threw load() exception
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$2.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:104)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:102)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4958)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
05-Oct-2022 09:12:11.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
05-Oct-2022 09:12:11.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
05-Oct-2022 09:12:11.075 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@23ec2bdc')
05-Oct-2022 09:13:32.365 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Servlet.init() for servlet [WEBAPI] threw exception
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$2.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:104)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:102)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:788)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
05-Oct-2022 09:13:32.366 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [WEBAPI]
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$2.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:104)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:102)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:788)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: From the error, it appears a jersey library may not be configured properly or missing in your CRM webapp that uses a framework called WEBAPI. The issue is definitely during loading the application on startup. It would be a wise idea to double check the server.xml config isettings conform suitable to the activity.

Comment: [/crmDb2API-1.0]  and    attributeAdded('StockTicker' , 'async.Stockticker@23ec2bdc' appear to have signifigance. Too, and surrounding port 8080 init. and with .asm. class libraries. Of 8080 a web service WSDL may have different port (machine) requirement some where not localhost. Re, Async a resource somewhere.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant The application is pure java web app. It is used to communicate to CRM system. I tried to run it on fresh installation of Tomcat 9, but with no luck. As for StockTicker, I have no clue what it means. The application does not generate WSDL.

Comment: Your WEBAPI servlet url pattern appears it gets directed to by "anything" , if it is not a default web container folder, then that should at least be the webapp folder name as part of the path. Also, had a thought did you import the libraries as save into project on compile. And is the compiler and runtime suitable JVM for ee8, ee8 is not core se8 e.g. not se core 1.8.0_202 inclusive Tomcat level check.

Comment: Definitely a configuration problem of some type. 
Rare times server.xml requires to be notified of dependency jars and ext paths, but probably the web.xml and any other webapp conf files if required . com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppRe esourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)

Comment: <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup> There are no other servlets. If loaded at request made time use -1

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a configuration problem of some type. Rare times server.xml requires to be notified of dependency jars and ext paths, but probably the web.xml and any other webapp conf files if required . com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppRe esourceConfig.(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89) The give-away is seeing <INIT> at webapp loading in stderror file or Catalinaout file.

**<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup> There are no other servlets. If loaded at request made time use -1**

**attributeAdded('StockTicker' , 'async.Stockticker@23ec2bdc' ) seems to be a class instantiated and added onto the live ServletContext object that will stay instantiated for start to end of application lifecycle. This seems to be a forerunner of web services API if there is no wsdl definition and registry (*async* - can input and output at same time).**

Presumably with a CRM you will be using a DB driver and either pool or load method.
That if anything when it's past this error will be the next (that's the context.xml lines to configure a pool and driver usually).

Your WEBAPI servlet url pattern appears it gets directed to by "anything" , if it is not a default web container folder, then that should at least be the webapp folder name as part of the path.

Comment: attributeAdded('StockTicker' , 'async.Stockticker@23ec2bdc you will find that in the startup class source Contextinit.java , it resides with the servlets.